# How to read PDF files with no desktop?

Tags: command-line, pdf

If use the system only with command line and do no desktop booted. How to read PDF files in such case? If Ubuntu 20.04 for desktops is used.

Comment: Depending on the types of PDF files; you can `view` them as they're mostly just XML... the pictures & graphics can make certain PDF files a *pain* to view, but if you're *somewhat* familiar (*even if only marginally*) with the viewing of XML files it's pretty easy & use just search for what you want to read...  (FYI: I've used this to extract data that was a *pain* on a GUI reader for copy/paste into replies in my gui).   Providing your OS & release details may allow users of this site to offer more but we currently don't know if you're using a *deb* based or *snap* only based Ubuntu system?

Comment: @guiverc I'd use Ubuntu 20+.

Comment: @guiverc I use 20.04, conventional desktop version.

Comment: @guiverc I have a feeling this really varies, as I just tried to read a bank statement that appears almost completely as text in a PDF viewer, but no useful information was viewable.

Comment: Bank statements (*at least all I've received*) are usually encrypted, making it harder if not impossible to read using `view`.  I would **not** attempt to read anything with encryption on it (*as I'd only expect enough detail that the type of file can be recognized; not that I can read the content within it*)  but you are right.   Depending on how sophisticated the PDF is, what features were used, tools used to create it - results can be great, or terrible.

Comment: Bryan Lunduke wrote a series of articles years ago for a magazine, where the premise was *one month of using only terminal for everything* which covered PDFs, thus is likely where I'd go hunting for answers.  As I recall he gave it away part way into it, by which time he'd worked out work-arounds for almost everything which likely included reading PDFs  (*many of which weren't that fun*).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not expect to see graphics content of a PDF in a terminal, obviously. You can however view textual content of a PDF, if any, and provided the file is not encrypted. The standard `less` will already do a very decent job on its own:

```
less filname.pdf
```